# Crie uma sequencia de dados de 1 a 30 apenas com números impares. Use a função seq()

Tags: r

estou tentando resolver essa questao dada num manual mas nao consigo fazer com que a sequencia seja de numeros impares

Comment: Poste o código que já tentou, assim fica mais fácil para comunidade te ajudar

Comment: obrigado mas ja consegui o lance era comecar do 1 e ir incrementando por 2

Answer (score 2):

Basta prestar atenção nos parâmetros.

```
seq(from = 1, to = 30, by = 2)
```

- `from`: começo da sequencia
- `to`: máximo valor possível da sequência. Não propriamente o elemento final.
- `by`: incremento da sequência.